# What are the words above the staff called (especially at the beginning)?

Tags: learning, sheet-music

[image: "Boldly!" written at the beginning of a part of sheet music]

What is this text above the staff for, and what is it called?

Answer (score 8):

It's called a *Performance Mark*, *Dynamic Mark*, or *Directive*, meaning an instruction, generally from the composer, regarding exactly how a particular part should be played: Loud, Soft, Slow, Fast etc.

See [***Performance marks*** and subheadings there](http://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/2567-performance_marks)

***Boldly!*** is modern English. However, in classical music and more traditional scores and sheets, Italian terms are generally used (without exclamation points), such as these:

[image]

Further down we find this:

***risoluto risoluto        bold; strong***

Answer (score 0):

I've always known that as an 'expression marking'.  It's the composer's indication to the performer of the style and often speed of the piece.

Comment: Expressive indications go below the music, along with the dynamics. In the case of vocal parts, they go above the music, along with the dynamics.